# How to report a bad result in spam check on review late answers?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, review-audits, late-answers, spam-detection

I just reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/10899637).

I choose: No action needed, but the system says I failed because it's a spam answer:

"As far as I know, global variables are not passed to the workers, thus the above example should not work."

I don't see any sign of spam on that.

How / Where must I report this?

Comment: Consider it reported. The answer was deleted, but it wasn't deleted as spam, so at the very least the message you got is incorrect here.

Comment: i saw other question before with same issue but i click next and cant go back to reported it, so its a false positive case but, this can impact in the user rate? thanks for your help @AdamLear

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Unclear spam review audit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262175/unclear-spam-review-audit)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. The proposed dupe was actually about posts with spam flags that had been deleted by a diamond-mod. The post under discussion here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34310048) was deleted through review by normal users (10K SO users can see this).

Answer (score -1):

This is normal. The system occasionally throws the "possibly spam" banner on audits to make sure you're paying attention.

The answer was legitimately deleted for being Not An Answer (it was just a comment), so "No action needed" was the wrong response.

Comment: i was reviewing the last answer not question, the answer looks good, and i dont see it deleted even now, so the "spam" mark its just a way to abstract all the posible cases?

Comment: The answer *isn't* good. It is providing commentary only ("As far as I know, global variables are not passed to the workers, thus the above example should not work.") - it is making no attempt at all to *solve the problem*. It was deleted through review with the comment "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post."